# looking for meshlet generation algorithms

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry

I am looking for algorithms to create meshlets from triangulated meshes.
I searched for articles, but could not find any.
Maybe "meshlet" is not the right term?

I want to cluster the faces to have a maximum number of vertices each (for example 64) and a nearly equal normal vector, and each face within a cluster should be close to each other. The reason for this is early clipping / culling to speed up my rendering.

I've tried to do it myself, but it's not as easy as it seems. I got "bad" looking results. On closer inspection I saw that many meshlets are very small. Probably because adjacent faces have already been grouped into other meshlets, or the normal vectors are too different.

It also doesn't seem easy to keep the normal vectors similar without ending up with meshlets that are too small.

Which algorithms can I use? And what advantages do they have (compared to other algorithms)?

Edit: It seems unclear what I mean by meshlets. So I'll explain what I'm trying to do:

I want to group the faces of a geometry into individual groups (meshlets). I don't want to increase the number of faces.... This is a preprocessing step that needs to be done once when loading the geometry. Each of the meshlets gets a bounding sphere for clipping tests, a normal vector with additional angle (normal vector cone) for culling tests. If geometry rendering is foreseen, clipping/culling tests are performed beforehand, along with a level of detail (LoD) test. During rendering, the results of the culling/clipping/LoD tests are loaded to finally render only the parts of the geometry that survived these tests.

[image]

**Figure1** [Image source](https://metalbyexample.com/mesh-shaders/). This is an example of a result I am trying to achieve.

Comment: "I want to cluster the faces" would have made it easier to understand than "I want to split my geometries".

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for the hint. I've changed it :) I am sorry, english is not my mother tongue

Comment: Maybe super-faces can replace meshlets.

Comment: For fast clipping, you can also consider a hierarchy of bounding volumes (such as spheres). This allows efficient rejection even when zooming closely. You might integrate culling at some level in the hierarchy (where the normals are homogeneous).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy#:~:text=A%20bounding%20volume%20hierarchy%20(BVH,enclosed%20within%20larger%20bounding%20volumes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust One of the reasons I'm asking this question is to familiarize myself with mesh shaders. The bounding volume hierarchy would bring me to the same question (how to cluster)

Comment: The section on Construction is a little terse, unfortunately.

Comment: I think together with **Figure1** it is reasonably clear what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Yes, that's clear to me.

Comment: https://github.com/zeux/meshoptimizer  Keep reading on this link, the Turing mesh info is near the bottom.  I think this question is outside the computer graphics scope so don't be surprised if it gets closed.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/introduction-turing-mesh-shaders/ this has some info on creating the actual meshlets.